# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: html, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to src the image in my html. But getting some error that is `Access to image at 'https://kaberatech.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/voice-bot.jpeg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. I also upload the images on the new amazon web server S3 and set the properties to publicly accessable. when I'm hitting the url `https://kaberatech.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/voice-bot.jpeg` then it will load my image in the browser. But when I'm inserting this into the html code then it will showing me error. Below is my html code can anyone tell me that where is the problem

```
<div id="detail-line" class="detail-line"></div>
<div class="all-images w-embed">
     <img src="https://kaberatech.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/voice-bot.jpeg" crossorigin="1" alt=""/>
</div>
```

But when I'm using the below html code then its working fine

```
<div class="detail-line"></div>
<div class="all-images w-embed">
     <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ed67e44325d5f0e41baf4be/5ee4e05d7580a1cfe491156c_si-23.jpg?" crossorigin="" alt=""/>
</div>
```

With including this script below:-

```
<script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.220afd743d.js?site=5ed67e44325d5f0e41baf4be" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ed67e44325d5f0e41baf4be/js/webflow.ae4a2c7df.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

will I need to add a special script for amazon? If yes, can anyone suggest me what is it?

Comment: What does your console say? Is there a problem with preflight request?

Comment: @Kudlas — The quoted the error message in the question, and there is no preflight request.

Comment: @Quentin what I will need to enter in the cros policy of the bucket the code that is answered in the question?